# Regex pattern should allow only integers from 0 to 100 not allow decimal points

Tags: regex, input, integer

I have an input box and what I need is it should only allow values from 0 to 100 and It should not allow to enter decimal precision should allow only integers like 10, 25,...etc and not 10.5,0.5... etc.

What I tried is as follows:

```
<input   id="discount" name="discount"  placeholder="Discount" autocomplete="off" type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" value="0" maxlength="2">
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x7kz3rqv/1/)

Need to modify the `pattern="[0-9]*"`.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to restrict a numeric range, the best way to do so is to supply the `min` and `max` attributes. Also, if you wish to allow 100, you'll need to increase `maxlength`.

```css
input#discount:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
 <input id="discount" name="discount"  placeholder="Discount" 
        autocomplete="off" type="number" inputmode="numeric"
        min="0" max="100" maxlength="3"
        pattern="^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$">
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be "^[0-9]*$", add start and end indicator for your pattern

Comment: updated the fiddle as per your suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/x7kz3rqv/2/. But not working please help buddy

Comment: please take a look buddy